# MarketingCloud SDK - iOS turn on/off for GDPR?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, mobilepush

can I disable the salesforce SDK in my iOS application if the user chooses to not share their data with respect to the GDPR?

Basically, how does MarketingCloudSDK handle GDPR?

Answer (score 2):

The SDK handles GDPR in response to changes in the Marketing Cloud system itself - the server communicates the state of contact privacy (Do Not Track, Right to be Forgotten, Restriction of Privacy) to the SDK daily and the SDK will take the appropriate action (deleting PII, turning off services, etc.).

Fully documented here: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/sdk-implementation/data-privacy-iOS.html

Comment: As a user on my app who has decided to "toggle" the salesforce tracking to "off", what are the steps that I need to take to tell the Salesforce system not to track the user?

Comment: You will need to use the Contacts API or UI (for the Marketing Cloud server) to drive the right set of actions to enable and manage privacy modes. Contacts are "greater" than just MobilePush within Marketing Cloud and so must be managed in an overall way.